# laravel "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user" but 'users' table exists

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I am running Laravel 5.2, on Windows 8.1 using XAMPP with php 7.2, and I am trying to register a user using laravel auth register form with sqlite database. However when I try insert new record to table `users` I got error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: user

When I migrate database it creates users table. But when I try to insert new record in `users` table with register form it tries to access `user` table. So I created `user` table in database it works fine but the record is inserted in `users` table and not in `user` table.

**Migration**

```
public function up(){
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('role');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

public function down(){
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'role', 'username', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**AuthController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller{

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    protected $username = 'username';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'role' => 'required|max:7',
            'username' => 'required|unique:user',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'username' =>$data['username'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

thanks for help and sorry for bad english.

Comment: Not sure if it is just a typo but there is no `user` table, rather there is a `users` table. The eloquent model should do the insert into that table automatically anyways though.

Edit: Never mind I see that you noticed that already.

Comment: yes I think so but when I try to change with protected $table = 'tb_user' it's still try access user table.

Comment: see my answer, it solves your problem

Comment: Did you have any more issues?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. For now there is no issues.

Comment: if my solution helped could you mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is in the validation:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'role' => 'required|max:7',
        'username' => 'required|unique:user',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

You are checking if the username is unique in `user` not `users`, try this:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'role' => 'required|max:7',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

Also you will likely want to add a unique constraint on the migration.

Comment: thank you a lot, but i still do not understand why you add `required|unique:users,username` instead `required|unique:users` if it works fine.

Comment: Using `users,username` is explicitly saying check the users table username column for uniqueness. When you omit `username` it uses the field name you are validating as the column name.

Answer (score 1):

In your `users model` add `public $table = 'users'`  | `public $table = 'user'`

Comment: This fixed it for me but it was different case than in error but same error code. I renamed table name directly in migration that creates table and this error since. Even tried to clear cache, didn't work, but this did, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions

If you have a model User, then you must have the table as "users" not "user" in your database.

Comment: They know that, they are asking why it is trying to use user not users

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. It was due to

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('owner_id')->nullable()->constrained('user')->index();
```

instead of (note the s in users)

```
    $table->foreignId('owner_id')->nullable()->constrained('users')->index();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you tried using a different name in your model fillable .Try to make sure that the names are identical for example you can not use user_id in your migration database table then you use users_id in your user model